# Call to a member function subjects() on null

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, laravel-5

i'm facing an  error  Call to a member function subjects() on null . My project is by php and laravel.  My project is on live server. Its works fine normally but when i click to edit something or click update button then it shows Call to a member function subjects() on null . Only my current  browser facing this error but if i hit from another browser to my server its seems ok.

public function index()

```
{

    $featured_packages = Package::where('featured_package', 1)

        ->with('reviews', 'user')

        ->get();

    $popular_packages = Package::where('popular_package', 1)

        ->with(['class' => function ($query) {

            $query->pluck('name');

        }, 'reviews', 'user'])

        ->withCount('mcqs')->get();

    $class_id  = StudentClass::all()->random()->id;

    if (Auth::check()) {

        $class_id = auth()->user()->grad != '' ? auth()->user()->grad : $class_id;

    }

    $subjects = StudentClass::find($class_id)->subjects()->withCount('packages')->get();

    return view('frontend.index', compact('featured_packages', 'popular_packages', 'subjects', 'class_id'));

}

public function about()

{

    $about = About::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();

    return view('frontend.about', compact('about'));

}

public function contact()

{

    return view('frontend.contact');

}

public function faqs()

{

    $faqs = Faq::orderBy('id', 'asc')->where('status', 1)->get()->groupBy('tab');

    return view('frontend.faqs', compact('faqs'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `findOrFail()` instead of `find()`, or just check it with conditional statement. Your `StudentClass::find($class_id)` could be null and it is worth to check it before chaining.

Answer (score 0):

Check if StudentClass exist first

```
$studentClass = StudentClass::find($class_id); 

if ($studentClass) {
       $subjects = $studentClass->subjects()->withCount('packages')->get(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#not-found-exceptions), you need to use the method `findOrFail()` like this :

```
$subjects = StudentClass::findOrFail($class_id)->subjects()->withCount('packages')->get();
```

Because if your `StudentClass` isn't found, you can't use your function `subjects()` on `null`.